# To set mat-list-item color constant until clicking the next list-item

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using  `<mat-nav-list>` component in which  `<mat-list-item>` is displayed as shown in below image:

[image]

Here when i click particular `<mat-list-item>` (eg Home 1), I want to change the text-color of `(Home 1)` and that text-color as to constant until i click another `<mat-list-item>` (eg Home 3), Like this:

[image]

How to do this? I am missing some css,Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-s1ojca?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html) link.

Comment: are you using this for routes?

Comment: Ya i am using this for routing.

Comment: you want this out of routing ?

Comment: I want it only for routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For routes you can use like this

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home1']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <mat-icon [class.active]="selected" matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
    <a matLine>Home 1</a>
  </mat-list-item>

  <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home2']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
    <a matLine>Home 2</a>
  </mat-list-item>

  <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home3']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
    <a matLine>Home 3</a>
  </mat-list-item>

  <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home4']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
    <a matLine>Home 4</a>
  </mat-list-item>

</mat-nav-list>
```

and in selection css

```
.mat-list-item.active{
  color: red;
  //any styles you like to add
}
```

here is the [slackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-activelinks) url  check this

Comment: can you post it as a new question? that selection-list question you asked

Comment: I have posted new question please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114339/to-change-text-color-in-mat-list-option