# To change text-color in mat-list-option

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-selection-list` component in which `mat-list-option`  is displaying a `contact list` as shown below:

[image]

Now the `background-color` is changing when i click particular `contact-name`(eg Graeme swan) and  `background-color` is constant until i click another contact , But i want to change the `text-color` also and **the tex-color should be constant until i click new contact**.

Hers is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-option-lj75yz?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.ts) link.

Comment: you want style changed in all selected contact? or the last clicked one?

Comment: Only last clicked.

Comment: then why you use selection list? you could use normal list

Comment: At that time of development i came to know that **selection list** was available with change in `background-color` feature , Since i was beginner to `angular`  i used **selection list**.

Comment: Actually inside the `list-item` i am displaying image too..:)

Comment: Like this `<a mat-list-item><img class="contact-img"  matListAvatar src="assets\images\img1.png" > <span class="contact-names">{{ link }}</span> </a>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to style your selection in list components as

html

```
<mat-selection-list #linkList >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let link of links;index as i" (selectionChange)="selectionChanged(i)" [class.active]="selectedItem === i">
    <a mat-list-item> <span class="contact-names">{{ link }}</span> </a>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

add these in ts file

```
  selectedItem:number = null;

      ....

  selectionChanged(i) {
      selectedItem = i;
  }
```

add these to css

```
.mat-list-item.active .contact-names{
  color: red;
}
```

[slackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-option-new) url

Comment: sorry i am unable to see  yours working **stackblitz** link.

Comment: i did the above code to show all selected items in the list active. as your requirement is not that i removed the link

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have saved my day...:)

Comment: It's working fine in **satckblitz** but not in my project do i need to do any imports??

Comment: no imports are needed. can you inspect and check weather the active class is applied to the mat-list-option while clicking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182995/discussion-between-prashanth-gh-and-akhi-akl).