# To highlight the data on click in Iist with selection component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `List with selection` component to display contacts as list, which appears like this:

[image]

Here when i click on the `contact-name` (eg contact 1). I want to change the `text-color` of `contact 1` and the `text-color` should be the same until i click another `contact-name` (eg contact 3).
 Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-list-vw5zar?file=app/list-selection-example.html) link

Comment: is my stackblitz what you were looking for  ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114339/to-change-text-color-in-mat-list-option/53114430?noredirect=1#comment93126632_53114430
you can check the answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple css hack to achive it as below:

```
.mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  .mat-list-item{
        color : blue;
    }
  }
.mat-list-option[aria-selected="false"] {
  .mat-list-item{
        color : black;
    }
  }
```

When [aria-selected="true"] is true change color to blue.
Also, since you need only one item selected at a time you would need to do the following in .ts:

```
@ViewChild(MatSelectionList) selectionList: MatSelectionList;
ngOnInit(){
   this.selectionList.selectedOptions = new SelectionModel<MatListOption>(false);
}
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-list-qwi7fv

Comment: For the css i,e `.mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  .mat-list-item{
        color : blue;
    }
  }`  I am getting an warning **Con't use empty ruleset**

Comment: In my stackblitz demo? If your using in ur own code, check curly braces are closed properly.

Comment: Ya i have checked everything is fine.

Comment: Are you using .scss or .css?

Comment: I am using .css

Comment: Yep, so either change to .scss or convert the .scss code to equivalent css. For the question u hv put, a working example is already provided.

Comment: Glad it helped. Pls upvote mark as answer to close this. quest.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event mouseover which will highlight your contact on over (change the css class with ngclass or something like that, or just a NgIf)
and you add another event mouseout which remove the highlight

EDIT : stackblits : https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-list-jdqn8n

EDIT EDIT : change mouseover to click

Comment: I am still on learning phase, I dont know proper usage of 'ngclass` if possible please edit in **stackblitz** link.

Comment: I never used stackblitz, I made the modification but I don't know how to save them :D

Comment: after modification `save` and click the `fork` button, then give the `forked URL`.

Comment: What issue you are facing ??

Comment: I want to change `text-color` on mouse click not on mouse hovering.

Comment: Just change the event from mouseover to click

Comment: In your edited **stackblitz** link, The list has been disappeared..:)

Comment: I just put 1 contact for the example